# Cl.exe returing error code D8050

Tags: visual-c++

I have the following error on fresh windows 8 install with microsoft visual studio ultimate 2013 :

```
cl : Command line error D8050 : cannot execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
 Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\c1xx.dll': failed to get command line into debu
g records
```

The weird thing is that trying to compile in an admin cmd is working....
I tried to change ownership/rights of the VS12 folder but it changes nothing.

```
cl /Fobin\x64\Release\file.obj /c src\file.cpp 
/TP /nologo /MP /GS /W4 /wd4800 /wd4138 /wd4530 /wd4512 /wd4996 /wd4251 
/wd4661 /wd4505 /WX- /Gd /Zi /Gm- /Zc:wchar_t /errorReport:prompt /Zc:forScope 
/Fplibvideostitch.pch /FS /Fdvc120.pdb /fp:precise /GL /O2 /Oy- /Oi /MD /Ot 
/DWIN32 /D_USE_MATH_DEFINES /D_WINDLL /DNOMINMAX /D_CONSOLE /DNDEBUG
"/IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include"
```

Comment: Very obscure.  The 64-bit compiler rarely ever is used so it is a given that you are running the tool chain in an unusual way.  Omitting details about that doesn't help us help you.  Keep in mind that it might be an accessibility problem with the directory where the .obj files are stored.  Disable anti-malware.  Tinker with /GL, it needs to store command line options in debug records so the linker can restart the back-end when it applies the PGO optimizations.

Comment: I tried to remove /GL and other optimization flags but it didn't solve the issue.
I do not choose that compiler, it is the one that have automatically been chosen by SCons, but I guess if it is working in admin console there should be a way to make it work.
Will try to investigate on the directory where obj files are stored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this issue with a cleared environment, and it was resolved (at least in part) by setting the TMP environment variable.

Comment: Might be a noob question but what is TMP?

Comment: TMP folder is set for new user, can be modified -    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ok, I don't have the machine/setup anymore but I will upvote + accept hoping it will help others ;)

Comment: It is probably important to note that the issue occurs due to cl.exe not seeing TMP. Unless Scons passed through the environment from the OS or somehow set TMP in the environment that calls cl.exe, cl would get confused and try to use %systemroot% as TMP. That's why calling Scons from admin command prompt works.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my time! But I had  a little different case. My TMP was set to an unexisting folder. Unsetting of the TMP was a solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error after I cleaned up my C drive (deleted temporary files of all sorts). I was able to fix it by re-setting the environment variables for Visual C++ command-line tools. This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx) was my reference.
I was building 64 bit.

Run cmd as admin.

```
c:\>cd YourVSInstallDir\VC
c:\YourVSInstallDir\VC>vcvarsall.bat amd64
```

Answer (score 2):

I had my `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%` vars pointing to a directory that contained a `$`. Replacing it with an `_` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue happened on a machine where I set up a GitHub Actions self-hosted runner. I think it happened because I was messing with the folder where the git checkout of the VS project was with a user I was logged in as which was a different user than what GitHub Actions service was using to build. So I think it was a permissions issue. To resolve, I just deleted the whole folder since the GitHub Actions workflow will recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting fixed it for me!

I encountered this issue after a build failed due to running out of disk space. After clearing a lot of space, any subsequent build attempts failed with the D8050 error. Failing to come up with any better solution, I decided to give the age-old "fix" to all Windows problems: rebooting the system. And it worked! My guess is that some temporary setting was stuck in the wrong state, and rebooting cleared it up.