# VS2017 - Build returns D8050: failed to get command line into debug records

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using VS2017 (Enterprise) to build a project. I'm pretty new to VS and especially to setting up my machine for a big project, so please do let me know if you need more info.

A while ago, my build was working fine, all cpp files were compiling well. Then I made some changes to a few cpp files (harmless little changes). But after I restarted my machine, I keep getting a

```
D8050: failed to get command line into debug records
```

The full error message is:

```
D8050   cannot execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\c1xx.dll': failed to get command line into debug records   projectnameC:\Users\username\Documents\reponame\projectname\cl  1
```

However, this seems to be a really outdated error. I can't find the official support doc for this error (when I click on the error code on VS, it leads me to the support main page) and all the S/O questions are from 3-4 years ago. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547214/cl-exe-returing-error-code-d80500) question's answer suggests changing the TMP variable, but this can't be found under Properties anymore.

Just fyi, my OS is Windows 8, and my computer shut down abruptly while the project was building (it's a borrowed laptop, battery is old). I'm wondering if that has anything to do with this issue.

Again, please let me know if you need more details (eg logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suggested by a friend to do a clean build (clean + rebuild), but this also failed.

What did solve my problem was **deleting and reinstalling VS all over again**. This reset the program files folder for VS and my build is working again.

I did uninstall McAfee at the same time, because I saw somewhere that antivirus software might be disturbing the build, but I'm not sure if this affected the build.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by switching to a user with admin rights, I had a feeling this was something related to user-permission rights

Comment: it seems to be indeed connected to user rights. (I happened to me after updating my Windows password because I was connecting over an old SSH daemon). However, building with admin right sounds like a *bad* suggestion generally speaking. Better try with a clean windows session first.

Comment: seems that my session was missing `USERPROFILE` environment variable ^^"